# How to store and access MySQL query result in variable/object in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am learning Node.js and very new to it. I have a scenario where I need to run the query and get the result. Later I want to check some conditions and based on that appropriate actions I need to take.

```
pool.query('SELECT * FROM tournament WHERE id = ?', [tournamentId],
        (error, results) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
                const tournament = results;
               console.log(tournament)
               console.log(tournament.status)
                if (!tournament ) {
                    console.log('Tournament not found');
                    
                }else if(tournament.status === 'completed') {
                    console.log(tournament);
                   
                }else if(tournament.status === 'full') {
                   console.log('Full');
                }

              })
```

As you can see it is in very initial stage. However, my query is retuning the result.

In the Console Log I can see below result:

```
[
  RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    uid: 1,
    status: 'completed'
  }
]
undefined
```

I don't know why `tournament.status` is returning undefined. Am I declaring a variable incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

An array is being returned. If you did console.log(tournament[0].status), you would get the result (assuming the array is not empty).

Comment: thanks let me try. By the way to how to check if array is empty or not.